# Use PRESS statistic to select the best model

Tags: r, cross-validation, model-selection

I am given the following problem.

So I am asked to simulate data for 50 patients. Each patient has 15 features. I am told that the first 10 variables come from a multivariable Gaussian distribution with mean = 0 and a covariance matrix that equals to an identity matrix. The variance must be equal to 1.

For the rest 5 features, 1 am given the following formula to sample from

$$\mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{ij}} \sim \mathrm{N}\left(0.2 \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{i} 1}+0.4 \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{i} 2}+0.6 \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{i} 3}+0.8 \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{i} 4}+1.1 \mathrm{X}_{\mathrm{i} 5}, 1\right), \mathrm{j}=11, \ldots, 15 \text { and } \mathrm{i}=1, \ldots$$

The same applies to the y variable (target) which is given by the following formula.

$$Y_{i} \sim N\left(4+2 X_{i 1}-X_{i 5}+2.5 X_{i 7}+1.5 X_{i 11}+0.5 X_{i 13}, 1.5^{2}\right), i=1, \ldots, 50$$

So in R, I did the following.

```
sample <- rnorm(50*10, mean=0,sd=1) 
reshape <- matrix(sample, 50, 10)
#calculate the mean of x
m_x <- mean(0.2*reshape[,1] + 0.4*reshape[,2] + 0.6*reshape[,3] + 0.8*reshape[,4] + 1.1*reshape[,5])

#sample for variables 11 to 15
for(i in 1:5){
  reshape <- cbind(reshape, rnorm(50, mean=m_x, sd=1))
}

#calculate the mean for y
m_y <- mean(4+ 2*reshape[, 1] - reshape[, 5] + 2.5*reshape[, 7] + 1.5*reshape[, 11] + 0.5*reshape[, 
13])
#sample based on m_y to generate the target variable
reshape <- cbind(reshape, rnorm(50, mean=m_y, sd=1.5^2))

df <- as.data.frame(reshape)
```

Finally, I am asked the following question:

**Select the full model as well as the model that generated the data. By using 5 fold cross-validation and the function PRESS (Prediction Error Sum of Squares) find which model fits your data best by using your own R code.**

What does this mean exactly? PRESS is actually a leave-one-out cross-validation technique. How can I use a 5 fold cv here? What does the model that generated the data has to do in this? I think what it means is from all possible 2^15 models choose the one with the best PRESS statistic (perhaps a 5-fold press static).